# Adyen Payment: Save card token and make payment later from token

Tags: php, adyen

Is possible to allow adyen keep creditcard details and make payments from customers on basis of token or customer id  instead of credit card information.
I checked adyen tokenization method,I cannot find any api documention for tokenization method(similar to stripe payment).

Any one Please  suggest to me .

Answer (score 6):

To expand on uselight's answer, you can definitely tokenize card details.

Adyen uses a shopper concept that acts as a bucket to store saved details in. This `shopperReference` is defined by you and any payment method that supports recurring charges can be stored against this id.

To store a credit card, first you need to accept the card details using CSE (Client Side Encryption). This will encrypt the card details on the client's browser before submitting it to your own server and allows you to have full control on how the input fields can look. Here is an example form:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://test.adyen.com/hpp/cse/js/adyen.encrypt.js"></script>
<form method="POST" action="payment-request-handler.php" id="adyen-encrypted-form">
    <input type="text" size="20" data-encrypted-name="number"/>
    <input type="text" size="20" data-encrypted-name="holderName"/>
    <input type="text" size="2" data-encrypted-name="expiryMonth"/>
    <input type="text" size="4" data-encrypted-name="expiryYear"/>
    <input type="text" size="4" data-encrypted-name="cvc"/>
    <input type="hidden" value="[generate this timestamp server side]" data-encrypted-name="generationtime"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Pay"/>
</form>
<script>
// The form element to encrypt.
var form = document.getElementById('adyen-encrypted-form');
// See https://github.com/Adyen/CSE-JS/blob/master/Options.md for details on the options to use.
var options = {};
// Bind encryption options to the form.
adyen.createEncryptedForm(form, options);
</script>
```

All the fields with the `data-encrypted-name` attribute will be removed and replaced with a single `adyen-encrypted-data`. From here, your php server can use our provided [php api library](https://github.com/Adyen/adyen-php-api-library) to perform the authorization call. To save the details for later, include the `shopperEmail`, `shopperReference` (which is the id you specify for the shopper), and the `recurring.contract`. The recurring contract value will generally will be `RECURRING`. Be sure to store the pspReference for later as this will be used to match up the saved details.

```php
$client = new \Adyen\Client();
$client->setApplicationName("Adyen PHP Api Library Example");
$client->setUsername("[YOUR USERNAME]");
$client->setPassword("[YOUR PASSWORD]");
$client->setEnvironment(\Adyen\Environment::TEST);

$service = new Service\Payment($client);

$json = '{
  "amount": {
    "value": 999,
    "currency": "USD"
  },
  "reference": "payment-test",
  "merchantAccount": "[YOUR MERCHANT ACCOUNT]",
  "additionalData": {
    "card.encrypted.json": ' . $_POST['adyen-encrypted-data'] . '
  },
  "shopperEmail" : "wyldstallyns@email.com",
  "shopperReference" : "shopperref123456",
  "recurring" : {
    "contract" : "RECURRING"
  }
}'

$params = json_decode($json, true);

$result = $service->authorise($params);
$pspReference = $result.pspReference;
```

After you receive the result of AUTHORISED, you can perform a lookup of the `shopperReference` to get the token used for recurring charges via the `listRecurringDetails` call.

```php
$service = new Service\Recurring($client);
$recurring = array('contract' => \Adyen\Contract::RECURRING);
$params = array('merchantAccount' => '[Your Merchant Account]', 
  'recurring' => $recurring, 
  'shopperReference' => 'shopperref123456'
);
$result = $service->listRecurringDetails($params);

$recurringToken = '';
foreach($result['details'] as $detail) {
    if($detail['RecurringDetail']['firstPspReference'] == $pspReference) {
            $recurringToken = $detail['RecurringDetail']['recurringDetailReference'];
    }
}
```

You use this `recurringDetailReference` to perform future charges.

```php
$service = new Service\Payment($client);

$json = '{
  "amount": {
    "value": 999,
    "currency": "USD"
  },
  "reference": "recurring-test",
  "merchantAccount": "[YOUR MERCHANT ACCOUNT]",
  "selectedRecurringDetailReference":' . $recurringToken . '
  "shopperEmail" : "wyldstallyns@email.com",
  "shopperReference" : "shopperref123456",
  "recurring" : {
    "contract" : "RECURRING"
  }
}'

$params = json_decode($json, true);

$result = $service->authorise($params);
```

Hopefully this is helpful. Check out the [Recurring Documentation](https://docs.adyen.com/developers/payments/products-and-subscriptions/recurring-payments) as well.

Comment: Is it possible to create a token without making a payment? So just to enter the credit card details?

Comment: @AdemDinarević you can pass the amount as 0, still a payments request but for most banks, this doesn't ever show up as an actual charge.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are looking for recurring payments. If so, you might want to do this, passing card details through client-side encryption:

```
curl -u "ws@Company.YourCompany":"YourWsPassword" \
 -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
 -X POST --data \
 '{
     "additionalData": {
        "card.encrypted.json":"adyenjs_0_1_4p1$..."
     },
     "amount" : {
         "value" : 20000,
         "currency" : "EUR"
     },
     "reference" : "Your Reference Here",
     "merchantAccount" : "TestMerchant",
     "shopperEmail" : "s.hopper@test.com",
     "shopperReference" : "Simon Hopper",
     "recurring" : {
        "contract" : "RECURRING"
     }
 }' \
 https://pal-test.adyen.com/pal/servlet/Payment/v18/authorise
```

To use these details later, you should submit only this data:

```
curl -u "ws@Company.YourCompany":"YourWsPassword" \
 -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
 -X POST --data \
 '{
     "amount" : {
         "value" : 20000,
         "currency" : "EUR"
     },
     "reference" : "Your Reference Here",
     "merchantAccount" : "TestMerchant",
     "shopperEmail" : "s.hopper@test.com",
     "shopperReference" : "Simon Hopper",
     "selectedRecurringDetailReference" : "LATEST",
     "shopperInteraction" : "ContAuth",
     "recurring" : {
        "contract" : "RECURRING"
     }
 }' \
 https://pal-test.adyen.com/pal/servlet/Payment/v18/authorise
```